# Regex find occurrence in a string and return matched block from start of char to end of char

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a regex for the following situation.

I have this css:

```
$str = "#button_1589817804107 .omw-custombutton button {font-family:Rubik !important; font-weight:normal !important; font-style:normal !important;}
#button_1589817804307 .omw-custombutton button {color:red}
#button_1589817804407 .omw-custombutton button {font-family:Rubik; font-weight:300 !important; font-style:italic !important;}";
```

I need to preg_match_all (php) this string so I can find every occurrence that matches Rubik but it returns the string from `{` to the last `}`, so basically returned the following array of matches found:

```
[0]="{font-family:Rubik !important; font-weight:normal !important; font-style:normal !important;}"
[1]="{font-family:Rubik; font-weight:300 !important; font-style:italic !important;}"
```

I'm trying to figure it out, but a can't find a way. Regex it's not for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

bruno,
I have to guess exactly what you want, but would this do the trick?

```
preg_match_all (/^.*Rubik.*$/m, $str, $res);
```

Comment: i wall to find all the "RUBIK" string inside the main string and returns the sub string:
{.*"rubik".*}
start with { ends with } and contains RUBIK and only that string

Comment: {font-family:Rubik; etc...} matches
{color:rred} dont match

so the output should be "{font-family:Rubik; etc...}"

Comment: i thnk i got it: /{.*(rubik).*}/i

Comment: thank you for pointing me out